# SASS offset position mixin troubles

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I've been trying to make an offset positioning mixin for the past couple of hours. I've been struggling with lots of errors, I cant understand what is wrong.

Here is the latest version,

```
@function is-offset-prop-valid($value) {
    $values: auto initial inherit 0;

    @return (type-of($value) == number and not unitless($value)) 
          and (index($values, $value) != false);
}

@mixin position($position, $args) {
    $offsets: top right bottom left;

    @each $offset in $offsets {
        $i: index($args, $offset);
        @if $i == length($args) {
            @error "Empty offset values not allowed";
        } else {
            @if is-offset-prop-valid(nth($args, $i+1)) {
                #{$offset}: nth($args, $i+1);
            } else {
                @error "Set value #{nth($args, $i+1)} not a valid property for #{$offset}";
            }
        }
    }

    positon: $position;
}
```

Normally I would have the `nth($args, $i + 1)` set as variable, but for the sake of this example, I left it like that.

When I use the mixin

```
.abs {
  @include position(absolute, top 10px);
}
```

I get this error from the inner if statement:

```
Set value 10px not a valid property for top
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your code and rewrited it a bit. Sassmeister [demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/03e36be7d1eb5c24cc39a9968d8dc154).

At first, `is-offset-prop-valid` function is now more readable.
Secondly, mixin `position` does loop through arguments (`$args`), not through `$offsets`. And I added more argument checks (look at comments). And you need to write `@` symbol before `else`: `@else`.

```
@function is-offset-prop-valid($value) {
  $values: auto initial inherit 0;

  $is-numder: type-of($value) == number;
  $is-unitless: unitless($value);
  $match-default-values: index($values, $value) != null;

  @return ($is-numder and not $is-unitless) or $match-default-values;
}

@mixin position($position, $args...) {
  $offsets: top right bottom left;

  @if length($args) == 0 {
    @error "Empty offset values not allowed.";
  }

  @each $arg in $args {
    // Check offset key-value pair
    @if length($arg) != 2 {
      @error "Invalid pair offset-name: offset-value.";
    }

    $offset: nth($arg, 1);
    $value:  nth($arg, 2);

    // Check offset name parameter
    @if index($offsets, $offset) == null {
      @error "Invalid offset name: `#{$offset}`.";
    }
    // Check offset value parameter 
    @if not is-offset-prop-valid($value) {
      @error "Set value `#{$value}` not a valid property for `#{$offset}`.";
    }

    #{$offset}: $value;
  }

  position: $position;
}

.abs {
  @include position(absolute, top 10px, left 23px);
}
```

But it seems to me that a simple set position is much simpler and more understandable:

```
.abs {
  top: 10px;
  left: 23px;
  position: absolute;
}
```